# Mapping permutations with repetitions to an index

Tags: permutations

I am looking for a way to map permutation with repetitions written in big array (for example with million elemenths) to an index written in other array. Every element in array can have values from 0 to 255. How to achieve that?

Example (not calculated):

```
Perm={4,67,23,33,45,23,255,234,67,99,67} => Index={34,23,44,23,23,7,254}
Perm={4,67,23,33,45,23,255,234,67,99,68} => Index={34,23,44,23,23,7,255}
Perm={4,67,23,33,45,23,255,234,67,99,69} => Index={34,23,44,23,23,8,0}
```

etc.

Comment: Give an example. It sounds like your second array can only store up to $256$ indexes, while your first array is holding a lot more than that.